# Using Reduce() to calculate percentiles or variance in R

Tags: r, list, vector

In the same way that I calculate the average of each position in the parallel vectors combined in the list, I would like to look for percentiles (0.05 and 0.95), variance or standard error.

```
LOC_GI_1950a <- rnorm(100,5,2)
LOC_GI_1951a <- rnorm(100,7,3)
LOC_GI_1952a <- rnorm(100,1,2)
LOC_GI_1953a <- rnorm(100,2,3)
LOC_GI_1954a <- rnorm(100,5,2)
LOC_GI_1955a <- rnorm(100,7,3)
LOC_GI_1956a <- rnorm(100,8,2)
LOC_GI_1957a <- rnorm(100,2,5)
LOC_GI_1958a <- rnorm(100,5,1)
LOC_GI_1959a <- rnorm(100,7,1)
LOC_GI_1960a <- rnorm(100,1,2)
LOC_GI_1961a <- rnorm(100,6,3)

LOC_GI_Annuala <- list(LOC_GI_1950a,LOC_GI_1951a,LOC_GI_1952a,LOC_GI_1953a,LOC_GI_1954a,
                       LOC_GI_1955a,LOC_GI_1956a,LOC_GI_1957a,LOC_GI_1958a,LOC_GI_1959a,
                       LOC_GI_1960a,LOC_GI_1961a)
LOC_GI_AnnualAvga <- Reduce("+",LOC_GI_Annuala)/length(LOC_GI_Annuala)
```

Comment: An easier option is `apply(array(unlist(v1), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), var)`

Comment: You wouldn't use Reduce for that. Reduce is for binary functions.  For percentiles you need to consider all of the data.

Comment: You can do `sapply(LOC_GI_Annuala, quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))`.

Comment: sapply(LOC_GI_Annuala, quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.95)) will give me percentiles of each vector, but I want a percentile for 1st element in each vector, 2nd element in each vector etc. So, I want to draw the elements one by one and look at their percentiles. My final output would have length 100. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @MIH You can modify Rui's code to `apply(array(unlist(v1), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), quantile, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))`

Comment: @akrun sorry but could you be more specific with your example? I am not sure how to make your example work

Comment: @MIH If you need a length of 100, then only one of the `probs` can be used `apply(array(unlist(v1), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), quantile, probs = 0.95)`

Comment: @akrun with apply(array(unlist(LOC_GI_Annuala), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), quantile, probs = 0.95) I get a matrix 10x10. How do I get a vector of 100 in the order corresponding to the original ones?

Comment: @MIH You can just wrap it with `c(apply(..`

Comment: @akrun thanks so much it works great!

Comment: @akrun final question - i gave a simple example but i have 64 vectors and each has 52 elements. How should i restructure the code? I tried apply(array(unlist(v1), c(2, 26, 64)), c(1,2), quantile, probs = 0.95) but it is not doing it right

Comment: @MIH Did you meant `c(apply(array(unlist(lst), c(26, 2, 64)), c(1,2), quantile, probs = 0.95))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `list` to an `array` and then use `apply` procedures to get the `mean`, `var`, etc. of each corresponding element

```
apply(array(unlist(v1), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), mean)
apply(array(unlist(v1), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), var)
```

As @RuiBarradas mentioned, the `quantile` can be used with `apply`

```
c(apply(array(unlist(v1), c(10, 10, 12)), c(1,2), quantile, probs = 0.95))
```